# iPhone app directory reorganization

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm trying to clean up my source directory tree by putting things into folders. When I move files, obviously I have to specify the relative paths in the target settings. If I don't, XCode will complain.

I've moved the following files to a subfolder from my project root:

- MyApp-Info.plist. I can tell XCode about this file by clicking on the "Choose Info.plist file" button in the target settings page.
- Default*.png. Those are fixed by entering the relative path in the Target > Info > Launch Image field.
- **en.lproj/MainStoryboard_*.storyboard**. Dunno how to fix this.
- **en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings**. Dunno how to fix this.
- There's also my source code files but that's easy to move around as these appear in the Build Phases > Compile Sources.

So my question is, what's required for specifying a subfolder for the rest of the supporting files in my target settings?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: XCode was just confused about the location of the storyboard. I removed the storyboard files and added them back in the project and at that point the storyboard is available in the dropdowns in the target settings page.